# WooCommerce field labels not shown

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

For some reason, my WooCommerce isn't showing labels nor placeholders for custom fields. No matter whether I'm adding the fields manually through functions.php (code below) or using plugins like 'WooCommerce Mailchimp', the fields shows up alright but there's no label next to it.

What might be causing this type of error?

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );

function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
     $fields['shipping']['shipping_phone'] = array(
        'label'     => __('Phone', 'woocommerce'),
    'placeholder'   => _x('Phone', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
    'required'  => false,
    'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
    'clear'     => true
     );

     return $fields;
}
```

Comment: What if you just use `'label' => 'Phone',`?

Comment: Doesn't make any difference :-/

Comment: Any other suggestions, please? :-)

Comment: I've experienced the same just before. It works for all other types just not `text`

Answer (score 0):

Change the key from `shipping_phone` to something else.

It seems like some key names are reserved even if they are not shown in the checkout fields list: http://docs.woothemes.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/